# Can't started hostednetwork, microsoft hosted network virtual adapter not present

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to set up a ad-hoc wifi network with windows 10, but when I enter the command `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, I get the message

```
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork) suggests that I should use the device manager to enable Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter, but that item does not appear, even when I show hidden items.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is `hosted network` still available in Windows 10? Probably not.
With Windows 10, you should be using this instead:
[image]